# pull out matching data another col from panda data frame into list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have list of sentences eg: `['i hate dogs', 'i like cats']`
and a pandas dataframe with sentences and type as cols.

what I want to do is match these to the same sentences from my list to the pandas dataframe col 'sentences' and pull out the 'Type' col

so i would have another list of Types that all match up to the sentences in the first list.

```
sentence_list = ['i hate dogs', 'i like cats']
Type_list = ['neg','pos']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With df being your dataframe and 'sentences', 'cols' its columns, you can do the following:

```
Type_list = df.loc[df.sentences.isin(sentence_list), 'cols'].to_list()
```